# Transfer program output from one Linux system to another

Tags: command-line, networking

I've two Linux systems (S1, S2), I want program/command execution output to transferred to S2 via Network(Please Suggest mode).

Suppose I say "Prime number finder" program on S1 run or Htop on S1, output on S2 terminal without much lag or delay.

Answer (score 2):

The classical way is **connecting over the network through ssh**: open a terminal on system S2, `ssh` into system S1. You now see the terminal prompt of S1. Run "htop". The output will only be delayed on a very weak network connection

Better yet, learn to work with a **multiplexer tool** such as `tmux` or gnu `screen`. In your S2, open a terminal, `ssh` into system S1 and start `tmux` (which must be installed on S1 - type "sudo apt install tmux` in your ssh session to have it installed. Now, you can close your terminal anytime on S2, or shut S2 down. Next time you ssh into S1, reconnect to the running session and you will see the terminal with applications running on S1 as you left it.

Comment: I saw a video tutorial saying something about NFS (network file system), won't that work? 

Because SSH means I am monitoring the output only in the second system, but I actually want the output to be transferred. For example, I say running a program which sends it's the load to connected systems to process and after processing the output of load transferred comes back to master computer. 

Hope I was elaborating my need.

Comment: As soon as you see the output on your other system, it is transferred. If you want to do something with the output on the other system, capture it in a text file and process it.

Comment: Yes, I want to store it in a file for further processing, you actually got my point here.

Comment: Your question only relates to "transferring" between computers on the network. As it is not allowed here to change questions after the fact, feel free to ask a new question requesting how to capture output of a remote program for processing on the client machine. One simple way indeed would involve having a network share (e.g. NFS) next to SSH, through which your client can then access the data for further processing.